# Is there something wrong with my Phaser syntax?

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

so I've tried to make this code work, but no matter how hard I try, it still won't work. My goal is to make my sprite move using cursors but it won't work. Also for some reason, if my sprite is depending on this:

```html
 gameState.cursors.this.input.keyboard.
 createCursorKeys();
```

I know my code is wrong, but I can't figure out how to fix it, here it is down there:

```html
   if (gameState.cursors.left.isDown) {
        gameState.player.setVelocityX(-160);
  } else if (gameState.cursors.right.isDown) {
        gameState.player.setVelocityX(160);
  } else {
        gameState.player.setVelocityX(0);
  }
        
    }
```

Thanks again stack community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `gameState.cursors = this.input.keyboard.createCursorKeys();` so they get assigned properly. This is assuming `gameState` is a global variable that can be seen from the current scope.